# Need help creating a regex for use in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Here is a snippet of the page:

```
<tr id="product_34980" class="even">
<tr id="variant_100329" class="variantRow">
```

I want to extract the 34980 and the 100329.  There could be multiple products and variants.  I will be using python.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/787016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link [@Kirill Polishchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787016/kirill-polishchuk) gives is a favorite on SO, it states clearly why you should not use regex for this.

If however you still persist on using a regex, then try:

```
<tr[^>]*id="([^"]*)"[^>]*>
```

Your match is now in capture group `#1`

Comment: @hwnd, nice edit (I'm lazy sometimes, not good for SO policy), but still at a lost. Was the regex wrong. It seemed to do what the OP asked. Certainly don't mind constructive criticism.

Comment: Thanks,  I think I will take another approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> p = re.compile('\d+')
>>> m = re.search(p, '<tr id="product_34980" class="even">')
>>> m.group()
'34980'
```